# Catch ActiveX Control Exception (prevent program stopped working)

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, activex, unhandled-exception

I use an ActiveX control (qlickview ocx) on my form and it work well but sometimes (on close form OR reopen a document in the control) my application will be hang with this windows message:

> Program stopped working...

Important Notes:

1. I used try catch block everywhere in my methods
2. The program does not enter into codes of the any catch blocks
3. I used `UnhandledExceptionEventArgs` in the "Main Method" but this event is not executed when the error occurred
4. I used `ThreadExceptionEventArg` in the "Main Method" but this event is not executed when the error occurred
5. I don't know reason of the error (Perhaps because of a bug of the used OCX control)
6. I don't want my end user see any message on this error occurred, just close the program

Comment: Could be something wrong with your machine, it does have a rather nasty problem with bolding text randomly.  But this is the standard way that ActiveX controls fail, they like to crash when they get unloaded and they have a memory management bug.  Kaboom when they release memory with a corrupted unmanaged heap.  If you cannot get support from the vendor then it is best to just get rid of the control.

Comment: @HansPassant, i did not find any guide in the qlikview support forum. so i can't handle this error and prevent application hang message. yes?